# Shrink disk image to eliminate free space

Tags: partition, dmg, disk-image, hdiutil

I created a larger-than-necessary writable disk image, copied content to it, then shrunk the partition with `diskutil resizeVolume`.

This left a big gap at the end of the partition table:

```
MEDIA: ""; Size 20 GB [41943040 x 512]; Max Transfer Blocks 2048
SCHEME: 1 APM, "Apple Partition Scheme" [1]
SECTION: 1 Type:'MAP'; Size 20 GB [41943040 x 512]; Offset 1 Blocks (41943039 + 1) x 512
ID Type                 Offset       Size         Name                      (4)
-- -------------------- ------------ ------------ -------------------- --------
 1 Apple_partition_map             1           63 Apple               
 2 Apple_Free                     64       262144 Explicit Record     
 3 Apple_HFS                  262208     25941040 disk image          
 4 Apple_Free               26203248     15739792 Explicit Record
```

I cannot figure out how to eliminate this gap and shrink the disk image down to the minimal size. The obvious command does nothing (with or without `-nofinalgap`):

```
hdiutil resize -sectors min image.dmg
```

I can even edit the file with a hex editor to change the partition count, which results in this partition table (note `Free` not `Apple_Free`), but even then I cannot get figure out how to eliminate the free space.

```
ID Type                 Offset       Size         Name                      (3)
-- -------------------- ------------ ------------ -------------------- --------
 1 Apple_partition_map             1           63 Apple               
 2 Apple_Free                     64       262144 Explicit Record     
 3 Apple_HFS                  262208     25941040 disk image          
   Free                     26203248     15739792
```

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't just make a sparsebundle, which would be 'self-sizing'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `-imageonly` to `hdiutil resize` seemed to do the trick:

```
hdiutil resize -sectors min -imageonly image.dmg
```

After this command completes, the size of the disk has shrunk to 15 GB and the free space at the end has been eliminated.

```
MEDIA: ""; Size 15 GB [30945024 x 512]; Max Transfer Blocks 2048
SCHEME: 1 APM, "Apple Partition Scheme" [1]
SECTION: 1 Type:'MAP'; Size 15 GB [30945024 x 512]; Offset 1 Blocks (30945023 + 1) x 512
ID Type                 Offset       Size         Name                      (2)
-- -------------------- ------------ ------------ -------------------- --------
 1 Apple_partition_map             1           63 Apple               
   Free                           64       262144
 2 Apple_HFS                  262208     30682816 disk image
```

This worked for me with both GPT and APM partition tables.

Comment: Interesting bug.  Looks like a good workaround.